# How do I solve $y'=\sqrt{x+y+1}$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I've tried all my little tricks and I can't make any progress on this.  I can't make it homogeneous because of that stray $1$.  I tried a substitution for $x+y+1$ but I couldn't work it out.

How is this done?

EDIT: With Artem's help below, I get as far as:

$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{u}+1}$

Then I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: "Then I don't know how to proceed." Funny, this is explained in my answer (and in at least one other) for 15 minutes before you write this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u = x + y + 1$; then $u' = 1 + y'$, and the equation now reads

$$u' - 1 = \sqrt u$$

Rewrite this as

$$\frac{u'}{\sqrt{u} + 1} = 1$$

Note that we can find a [nice antiderivative](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+1%2F%28sqrt%28t%29+%2B+1%29) for $1 / (\sqrt t  + 1)$; perhaps proceed by letting $t = \sqrt u$, so that
$$dt = \frac{1}{2\sqrt u} du \implies du = 2t dt$$

We would then be left with

$$\int \frac{2t}{t + 1} dt$$

Comment: Thanks.  I think I'm done with math.

Answer (score 3):

$$x+y+1=z\implies z'-1=\sqrt{z}$$

Comment: I had that written right in front of me but my brain didn't flag it as separable -_-  Thanks.  My brain is a troll.

Comment: I get to $\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{u}+1}$ and I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

$$z=\sqrt{x+y+1}\implies 1+y'=2zz'=z+1\implies 2z'-\frac{2z'}{z+1}=1$$